# Problem with textbox drop-down box in winform

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, dropdown

I have a simple winform project and when I set up the dropdown options for the textbox, sometimes there is an error and sometimes it works fine and I don't know what I wrote wrong.
this is my code

```
private void search_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.search.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
    this.search.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    string lang = StatementClump.SelectLanguage(3, language.Text);
    string lan = StatementClump.SelectLanguage(2, lang);

    // Retrieve the required data from the database and traverse it
    DataTable dt = StatementClump.SelectTable(2, lan, "rivenName", 
        lan, search.Text, "%");

    foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
    {
        source.Add(item[0].ToString());
    }

    // Setting the data source
    search.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
}
```

Here is the exception:

> Exception thrown in Warframe Search.exe at 0x77195C57 (shell32.dll): 0xC0000005: An access violation occurred while reading location 0x00000060.
>
> System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal An attempt was made to read or write protected memory. This usually indicates that other memory is corrupted.
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
> at WindowsFormsApp3.Program.Main() in E:\wf\WindowsFormsApp3\Program.cs:line 19
> line 19

```
 Application.Run(new Form1());
```

I changed the datasource so that instead of pulling it out of the database every time, it's a datatable, and that doesn't work either.

Comment: I may be wrong but I don't think you should be setting the autocomplete properties inside the TextChanged event.

Comment: There's a few solutions to this over at MSDN, please report any good ones that work for you as an Answer to your own question: https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e599b2e2-3cda-43ad-b15f-a69b4fea1a75/dynamic-filling-of-textbox-autocomplete-not-working?forum=winforms